# createRecord with custom ID in emberjs 2.x and Firebase 3.x

Tags: javascript, firebase, ember.js, ember-data, frontend

Until now, I saved all my data with the following line of code:

```
saveUser(params) {
      let newUser = this.store.createRecord('user', params);
      newUser.save();
      this.transitionTo('index');
```

This worked fine, but didn't allow for custom ID's in firebase, so I changed it into:

```
saveUser(params) {
      let newUser = this.store.createRecord('user', {
        id: params.loginId,
        name: params.name,
        nickname: params.nickname,
        imageUrl: params.imageUrl,
        email: params.email
      });
      newUser.save();
      this.transitionTo('index');
```

Processes them exactly as I want them to be stored on the Firebase database, so no problem there. I'm wondering though, and not finding any solution on the web, how I can combine the two, so that I don't have to bind every param. It's bound to give problems when I add/remove model properties.
Something I'm looking for would look like this (pseudo, yes I tried it, didn't work!):

```
let newUser = this.store.createRecord('user', {id: params.loginId}, params);
```

In short, I'm looking for the dynamic properties of `('model', params)`, but with the option to manually adjust 1 (or more) records without having to type out **all** of the params.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to customize your serializer to accomplish this.  The example in the docs is a good one, so it should be pretty straightforward: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/models/customizing-serializers/

I am, of course, assuming you are using Ember Data for your models.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed helped. I took a simple incremental ID for all records now. My motivation was to assign category names, user names, etc... as ID, for better url readability, but I can just as well use slugs where applicable. This way, I don't have to bind every param like I mentioned.